# Start / Stop Power when more power is added

Tags: switches, voltage-regulator

I have Blue LEDs wires to the interior of my car, My plan is to guy a Tachometer Shift light and wire it to red LEDs in my car so when I hit a certain rpm .... The red lights will turn on in the interior telling me to shift ( under dash )

PROBLEM :

At Night I have the Blue LEDs Running, what do I need to do so when I get to a certain RPM ( set on tachometer ) the blue lights will shut off and turn on the red LEDs instantly ..... then back to blue after I shift

( whole car Shift Light is what I'm trying to achieve )

Comment: Locating your Tach voltage on your instrument panel is the 1st step. If it is digital. Good luck. Can you report back the Voltage vs RPM when you find it?  Then you have to locate the BLUE led driver and report back the voltage swing across the diodes when Off or ON, If this is too difficult forget the Blue and blast it Yellow at X RPM voltage and Y RPM voltage with RED two coparators is all you need with the above Tach voltage. and a resistor to limit the current for each.

Comment: If people e-mail you their answers, it adds nothing to the stack-exchange board, and the answers are not available to potentially help other people. As such, I removed your e-mail address from your question. If you need to add further information, either edit your question, or add it in comments.

Comment: Comparator switch to ground with LED to +. Use 5 RED and 5 Yellow LEds to make ~10V and drop resistor will account for ~4V drop so 4V/0.02A= 200 ohm

Comment: Sorry guys , still having trouble figuring this out .... ok for Comment #1  Here is the GUage i will be installing  ( Taking apart and soldering Led's Under Dash to old Shift light )  Another Note ..... Blue Led is wired to a Toggle Switch ( on / Off ) and wired direct to the battery

http://www.aliexpress.com/item-img/UNIVERSAL-11K-RPM-GAUGE-GAUGES-ADJUSTABLE-RED-COLOR-SHIFT-LED-LIGHT-LAMP-TACHOMETER/550938242.html#

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Some details are need on Tach voltage still. Let us know what is it is.
Red Yellow can be a string of 5 instead of 4 then use 330 Ohm to get say 30mA drop on LEDs ( OK for short durations)otherwise 20mA max.

You ought to buy Blue,Yellow and Red 5mm LEDs and wire them with Anode to +. Comparator or Op Amp that can drive 20mA is active when low output. I added Cap in middle and 60Hz sawtooth to simulate shifting thru all the gears.. forever...

BLUE is always on and serves as Zener voltage reference voltage to comparators and adds to dash lights.If you figure out where what the BLue Voltage is your can use the internal dashlights for this. But I did not try to switch them off.
Yellow is ON set by 8K resistor, Red set 25% higher.(10K)

[**zoom**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XquG.jpg)  [**Simulator**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#$+0+5.0E-6+3.5993318835628396+32+5.0+50%0AR+96+128+32+128+0+4+60.0+5.0+5.0+0.0+0.5%0Ar+96+288+96+336+0+100000.0%0Aa+96+272+240+272+0+15.0+-15.0+1000000.0%0Ar+480+288+480+336+0+100000.0%0Aa+480+272+624+272+0+15.0+-15.0+1000000.0%0A162+672+272+672+320+1+2.0+1.0+1.0+0.0%0A162+672+240+672+288+1+2.0+1.0+1.0+0.0%0A162+672+176+672+224+1+2.0+1.0+1.0+0.0%0A162+672+208+672+256+1+2.0+1.0+1.0+0.0%0A162+320+208+320+256+1+2.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+320+176+320+224+1+2.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+320+240+320+288+1+2.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+320+272+320+320+1+2.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+720+352+720+400+1+3.6+0.0+0.0+1.0%0A162+720+384+720+432+1+3.6+0.0+0.0+1.0%0A162+720+416+720+464+1+3.6+0.0+0.0+1.0%0Ar+720+352+720+256+0+100.0%0Ar+672+160+672+144+0+670.0%0Ag+720+496+720+528+0%0Aw+288+320+320+320+0%0Aw+256+272+240+272+0%0Aw+672+320+624+320+0%0Aw+256+320+288+320+0%0Ac+528+32+528+80+0+1.0E-5+13.872000000000002%0Ag+528+80+528+96+0%0Aw+528+32+576+32+0%0Aw+96+336+96+384+2%0Aw+624+272+624+320+0%0Aw+256+272+256+320+0%0Aw+704+352+480+352+0%0Aw+480+352+480+336+0%0Aw+480+352+96+352+0%0Aw+96+352+96+336+0%0Aw+704+352+720+352+0%0Aw+480+80+480+112+0%0Aw+480+32+528+32+0%0Aw+480+80+480+32+0%0A162+720+448+720+496+1+3.6+0.0+0.0+1.0%0Aw+720+448+720+464+0%0Aw+720+384+720+400+0%0Aw+720+416+720+432+0%0Aw+720+256+720+128+1%0Aw+720+128+480+128+0%0Aw+480+112+480+128+0%0Aw+480+128+320+128+0%0Aw+672+144+672+128+0%0Aw+672+128+720+128+0%0Ar+320+160+320+144+0+753.0%0Aw+320+144+320+128+0%0Aw+320+160+320+176+1%0Ar+96+288+48+288+0+10000.0%0Ar+480+288+416+288+0+8000.0%0Ag+416+288+416+320+0%0Ag+48+288+48+320+0%0Ar+96+256+48+256+0+10000.0%0Aw+48+256+48+288+0%0Aw+320+272+320+288+0%0Aw+320+240+320+256+0%0Aw+320+208+320+224+0%0Aw+672+208+672+224+0%0Aw+672+240+672+256+0%0Aw+672+272+672+288+0%0Aw+480+256+368+256+0%0Aw+96+256+128+256+0%0Aw+128+256+128+208+0%0Aw+128+208+368+208+1%0Aw+368+208+368+256+0%0Aw+672+160+672+176+1%0A174+96+128+96+224+0+100000.0+0.6683+Tach+Cal+Pot%0Aw+96+224+96+256+0%0Aw+112+176+128+176+0%0Aw+128+176+128+208+0%0Ac+416+288+368+288+0+1.4E-7+-0.2573041709228912%0A172+480+32+432+32+0+6+13.872+14.6+12.0+0.0+0.5+Alternator+Voltage%0Aw+368+256+368+288+0%0Ao+0+64+0+34+13.09505467048489+9.134385233318143E-5+0+-1%0Ao+65+64+0+34+2.3384026197294445+9.134385233318143E-5+0+-1%0Ao+17+64+0+35+40.0+0.1+0+-1%0Ao+47+64+0+35+40.0+0.05+0+-1%0A)

Comment: what would the yellow be ? .... i do not have yellow lights .... The Blue Led's are Wired directly to the battery on a toggle ( on off switch )

Comment: Then cut out the Yellow circuit... It just gives you warning that Red is coming soon to reduce your reaction time.

Comment: Ok look here ..... I currently have somthing like This ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0JWVA5m1fhM  . ( WHOLE CAR )  ... i want the Blue lights to shut off when the red lights kick on ..... then when the red lights kick off blue comes back on.

Comment: Without your interface specs on voltage for LEDs and TAch, I cannot do a complete design, only proof of concept as I did. Now you need to do your part.

Comment: OK now i understand .... kinda like staging ..... That would be nice , but still stuck with the same situation ... from blue to yellow to red... back to blue

Comment: Voltage comming from Tach is 5V

Comment: Did you not see how it works in the simulator? Tach=5V = what RPM?

Comment: rpm is Changeable on Tach .... 5v at any rpm ...

Thank you for the help ... I really appreciate it , but im new to all this stuff so its a blurr to me .. but i am determined to figure it out

Comment: I cant help anymore until you produce a schematic of how your LEDS are driven. ...ground switch or High Switch.. current limited or resistor limited.. There are many subtle issues, perhaps beyond what you can determine.

Comment: Ok in the simulator ... the blue is constant ... i need blue to Shut off when yellow turn's on then yellow off when red turn's on

Comment: BLUE "+" is wired directly to the battery , BlUE '-" grounded on the Chassie of the car ..... Toggle Switch is on the positive wire to turn the lights on and off ....

Comment: Here is a schematic of what i currently have 
https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/w3a494/car-blue-wires/

Comment: What is the current drawn by the whole car BLUE LEDS

Comment: I do Believe 12 V 

( 12v Led's )

Comment: I see this is getting no where fast. Sorry need all the answers to my questions. I need current and same for Tach circuit. and just exceeded my free time for this question. Try other helpers